# Having trouble with menu slider in single posts - Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, slider

I am using a menu slider that stays highlighted on the active parent page. However, I created a "News" template page so when a visitor clicks on a single post, the page doesn't have the class "curren_page_item" which the JQuery needs to call for the active item. I tried coming up with a quick fix for this:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('.single')) {
        $('#menu-item-15').addClass('.current_page_item');
}
```

I want any page that the body tag has the class "single" to give the news page (#menu-item-15) the class "current_page_item" so the slider will work. But no luck there. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: This shouldn't be done with jQuery. This should be managed by your templates. Are you using a CMS? If so which?

Comment: I am using WordPress. I have my posts query through my News template.

Comment: In Wordpress you can make a post template, in a similar way you can make a page template. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/

Answer (score 0):

You should include the [`body_class($class)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function in your template files.

then you can manipulate it as you wish ..

Example :

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'AddCurrentMenuItemClass',1,2);

function AddCurrentMenuItemClass($classes,$item)
{
$link = site_url().$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($link, $item->url) !== false)
{
$classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
}
return $classes;
}
```